# How to read data from a big txt file in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

When i read data from a big txt file block by block ,I got the error as blow:

> Unfinished UTF-8 octet sequence (at offset 4096)
> code:

```
File file = File(path!);
RandomAccessFile _raf = await file.open();
_raf.setPositionSync(skip ?? 0);
var data = _raf.readSync(block);// block = 64*64 
content.value = utf8.decode(data.toList());
```

Comment: here https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/32

Comment: What I am doing is an app for reading novels. I want to read files page by page and record the location of reading, instead of loading all the original novels at one time, so ,How can I only read the contents of the specified range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF*8 is variable length encoding.
The error come from data not align to UTF8 boundary
Alternative way is to trim data byte on left and right before call utf.decode
This will lost first and last character. You may read and add more bytes to cover last character and align with utf8 boundary

```dart
bool isDataByte(int i) {
  return i & 0xc0 == 0x80;
}

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var _raf = await File('utf8.txt').open();
    _raf.setPositionSync(skip);
    var data = _raf.readSync(8 * 8);

    var utfData = data.toList();
    int l, r;
    for (l = 0; isDataByte(utfData[l]) && l < utfData.length; l++) {}

    for (r = utfData.length - 1; isDataByte(utfData[r]) && r > l; r--) {}
    var value = utf8.decode(utfData.sublist(l, r));
    print(value);
}
```

Optional read more 4 bytes and expand to cover last character

```dart
bool isDataByte(int i) {
  return i & 0xc0 == 0x80;
}

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var _raf = await File('utf8.txt').open();
    _raf.setPositionSync(skip);
    var block = 8 * 8;
    var data = _raf.readSync(block + 4);

    var utfData = data.toList();
    int l, r;
    for (l = 0; isDataByte(utfData[l]) && l < block; l++) {}

    for (r = block; isDataByte(utfData[r]) && r < block + 4; r++) {}

    var value = utf8.decode(utfData.sublist(l, r));
    print(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help，But what I am doing is an app for reading novels. I want to read files page by page and record the location of reading, instead of loading all the original novels at one time

Comment: I see, The problem should come from utf-8 character length vary from 1 to 4 bytes you may seek  to middle of the character. If  this the case,  2 ways to solve the problem 1)change encoding to UCS-16 which fix 2 byte per character 2)scan from begin of the file  and index location of new line and page break. then seek to index instead of block location

Comment: I Edited answer. Hope this close to your question. to record location should record location of first byte of character by checking !isdataByte()

Comment: Very useful solution,Although there is some duplication in the data obtained. Function(isDataByte) really helps me

Comment: The purpose of for(skip) loop is for testing only I try to seek as many location to ensure working of the concept.  forgot to remove :)